# Json Patch: Append multiple?

Tags: json-patch

Basically, how can I can combine these two operations?

```yaml
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/-
  value:
    name: php-src
    emptyDir: {}
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/-
  value:
    name: nginx-src
    emptyDir: {}
```

If I try like this, it deletes the existing entries:

```yaml
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes
  value:
    - name: php-src
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: nginx-src
      emptyDir: {}
```

I just want to append two new entries to the end of `/spec/template/spec/volumes` which is an existing array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** possible - the [Json Patch spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.1) only allows for adding singular values.